# How to change color tone

Tags: c#, algorithm, colors

I have read the article [Introduction to Color Theory](https://www.tigercolor.com/color-lab/color-theory/color-theory-intro.htm). Using that information, I have to change color's tone (I have to add grey color to current one)  programmatically (C#, .NET). How can I do it?

> Tones - adding gray to a pure hue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Adding gray" is fairly unclear.  Start mspaint.exe and click on Edit Colors.  Click the rainbow rectangle to pick a color.  Keep on eye on the Hue/Sat/Lum boxes.  Drag the slider on the far right up and down and note how the Luminance changes.  You make it darker by sliding it down, perhaps that's what you mean by "adding gray".  Or maybe you mean tinkering with the Saturation.  Try it for yourself.

You transform from the RGB color space to the HSL color space and back with [these formulas](https://web.archive.org/web/20141023005253/http://bobpowell.net/RGBHSB.aspx).

Comment: thank you for answer. I think, luminance means adding white or black colors to current one.  Saturation is that I am looking for. Thank you, Hans.